# Append "_Repeat" to Ambiguous column names

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that joins a table back onto itself in order to display orders that generated a repeat within a certain window.

The table returns something like the following:

```
id    |  value  |  note  |  id   |  value  |  note
------------------------------------------------------
01    |  abcde  |  ....  |  03   |  zyxxx  |  ....
06    |  12345  |  ....  |  09   |  54321  |  ....
```

In actuality, the table returns over 150 columns, so when the join occurs, I end up with 300 columns.  I end up having to manually rename 150 columns to "id_Repeat","value_Repeat","note_Repeat" etc...

I'm looking for some way of automatically appending "_Repeat" to the ambiguous columns.  Is this possible in T-SQL,  (Using SQL Server 2008) or will I have to manually map out each column using:

```
SELECT [value] AS [value_Repeat]
```

Comment: For a one off queries I often use Excel to generate the aliases.  Paste, transpose and a formula of  `name = name & "_Repeat,"` does the trick.  If you plan to reuse these names in multiple queries consider creating a view that sits on top of the original table, returning alias names.

Comment: I actually ended up going to Excel route to quickly bang out the query.  I'm not looking forward to modifying the TVF every time a new attribute is added, but it feels like the right thing to do when compared to dynamic sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I can see this working is to construct some dynamic SQL (ugh!).  I put together a quick example of how this might work:

```
CREATE TABLE test1 (id INT, note VARCHAR(50));
CREATE TABLE test2 (id INT, note VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO test1 SELECT 1, 'hello';
INSERT INTO test2 SELECT 1, 'world';
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(4096);
SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT ';
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + t.name + '.' + c.name + CASE WHEN t.name LIKE '%test2%' THEN ' AS ' + c.name + '_repeat' ELSE '' END + ','
FROM sys.columns c INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON t.object_id = c.object_id WHERE t.name IN ('test1', 'test2');
SELECT @SQL = LEFT(@SQL, LEN(@SQL) - 1);
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' FROM test1 INNER JOIN test2 ON test1.id = test2.id;';
EXEC(@SQL);
SELECT @SQL;
DROP TABLE test1;
DROP TABLE test2;
```

Output is:

```
id  note    id_repeat   note_repeat
1   hello   1           world
```

Comment: Figured this would be the case.  Appreciate the example! :)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible in T-SQL. A column will have the name it had in its source table, or any alias name you specify, but there is no way to systematically rename them.

For cases like this, it pays off to take it one level higher: write some code (using `sys.columns`) that generates the query you're after, including renames. Why do something manually for 150 columns when you have a computer at your disposal?